# Orthogonal Complement of a subrepresentation is a subrepresentation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ be a linear representation of $G$ and assume $(x\mid y)$ is a scalar product satisfying $(x\mid y) = (\rho_gx\mid \rho_gy)$ for all $g \in G$

If $W \subset V$ is stable under $G$, show that $W^\circ$, the orthogonal complement of $W$ under the scalar product $(x\mid y)$ is stable under $G$.

This is given as a remark after the first theorem in the book *The Linear Representation of Finite Groups* by *Jean Pierre Serre*. Before defining the scalar product, he discusses the existence of the subrepresentation $W^\circ$ in theorem 1. How to show $W^\circ$ is stable under $G$?

Comment: What is asked is to show that if $x$ satisfies $\forall y\in W:(x\mid y)=0$ then for every $g\in G$ the vector $\rho_gx$ also satisfies $\forall y\in W:(\rho_gx\mid y)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\in W^o$ and $g\in G$, you want to prove that $\rho_gx\in W^\circ$. Saying that $\rho_gx\in W^\circ$ means that, for every $y\in W$, $(\rho_gx\mid y)=0$. But\begin{align}(\rho_gx\mid y)&=\bigl(\rho_gx\mid \rho_g(\rho_{g^{-1}}y)\bigr)\\&=(x\mid\rho_{g^{-1}}y)\\&=0,\end{align}since $\rho_{g^{-1}}y\in W$.